# Host a non-profit digital newsletter

Tags: web-apps, pdf, newsletter

I've been tasked with digitizing a currently print-based newsletter for a small non-profit organization that I'm a member of and I'm having trouble finding a solution that fits my needs and am hoping someone here can help by making a recommendation

**The must-have requirements are**

- Ability to host PDF based newsletters
- Ability for users to create a username & password (i.e. sign up for access to the newsletter)
- Ability for the admin (me) to grant (or deny) access to folks who sign up
- Once users are granted permission they will have access to the back catalog of all newsletters (for free - this is all free)
- Ability to search the catalog of newsletters

**The nice-to-have requirements are**

- The ability for users to comment either at the newsletter level or,
  ideally, at the page or article level
- Ability to tag or add other meta-data to each newsletter / page /
  article etc.
- The ability for future issues of the newsletter to be created and
  published "digital / web first" within the platform instead of in
  InDesign and then exported to PDF
- The ability to allow or disallow download the PDF's (i.e. A read-only feature)

Is anyone aware of web-based SaaS solutions that offer this service that they can point me to?  If I can't find something that roughly fits these needs I assume I'll need to build out a WordPress solution (or something like that) but I'm hoping to not have to go down the custom dev route.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Great question. What about DRM/Security? Can the users granted permission to view a file also download it for offline viewing?

Comment: @Ryan You're right - the ability to not allow people to download the documents should be in the nice-to-have's - I will add it.  Have any ideas on a website / service / etc that can meet these requirements?